# Add a span element within a link to make it accessible (AA) with javascript

Tags: javascript, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm trying to modify a plugin in order to make it more modern and accessible. The problem is the icon: I need to add a span element with some text to make it readable but not visible.

My javascript is the following:

```
function _createInformationLink(linkText, linkHref) {
    var infoLink = document.createElement('a');

    _setElementText(infoLink, linkText);
    infoLink.href = linkHref;
    infoLink.target = '_blank';
    infoLink.style.marginLeft = '8px';

    return infoLink;
}
```

I tried to add a line in order to inject the html with .innerHTML like that:

```
function _createInformationLink(linkText, linkHref) {
    var infoLink = document.createElement('a');

    _setElementText(infoLink, linkText);
    infoLink.href = linkHref;
    infoLink.target = '_blank';
    infoLink.style.marginLeft = '8px';
    infoLink.innerHTML = "<span class='sr-only'>Close cookie policy</span>";

    return infoLink;
}
```

But it didn't work. Any suggestion?

UPDATE:

The function _setElementText is the following:

```
function _setElementText(element, text) {
    var supportsTextContent = 'textContent' in document.body;

    if (supportsTextContent) {
        element.textContent = text;
    } else {
        element.innerText = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on your definition of `_setElementText`, that may be what's causing the issue here for you. It may be helpful if you include your definition of `_setElementText`. I don't know exactly what you mean by "it didn't work" but I imagine if `_setElementText` sets `innerHtml` as well that will be overwritten when you set it to be the span.

Comment: function _setElementText(element, text) {
        // IE8 does not support textContent, so we should fallback to innerText.
        var supportsTextContent = 'textContent' in document.body;

        if (supportsTextContent) {
            element.textContent = text;
        } else {
            element.innerText = text;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the element then append it along with the text as such:

```
function _createInformationLink(linkText, linkHref) {
    var infoLink = document.createElement('a');

    _setElementText(infoLink, linkText);
    infoLink.href = linkHref;
    infoLink.target = '_blank';
    infoLink.style.marginLeft = '8px';
    var srSpan = document.createElement('span')
    srSpan.innerText = 'Close cookie policy'
    srSpan.classList.add('sr-only')

    infoLink.appendChild(srSpan);

    return infoLink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.innerHTML` maybe try using:

`infoLink.classList.add('sr-only')`

Comment: Yeah, but I need to create everything, not only a class. I need to create a span, a class to the span and some text inside it